# Missing end tag for "s:text" with Eclipse and Struts 2

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, struts2, java-ee-6

My Eclipse project has found an error on this line :

```
var SAI_Art26_Prorog_Rech = '<s:text name="labels.requete.requete.query.SAI_Art26_Prorog" />';
```

But everything is OK I never touched this line before and the project always worked.

I think it's a bug of Eclipse, or maybe not ?

[image]

Comment: More context is required: is this a JSP file? Are there any issues with lines above, e.g., missing a quote etc?

Comment: Yes I missed a line below without quote at the end of the s:text tag. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, all other things being equal, this is likely due to issues *above* where the issue was reported, like a missing quote.

As an alternative, you might consider rendering JSON instead of relying on `<s:text>` tags for a variety of reasons, the biggest of which is that all of these fields need to be JS-escaped (which I do not see reflected in your screenshot).

This can lead to difficult-to-diagnose errors because you need to look across domains (server, view, JS-in-the-view) instead of localizing problems.

Comment: In my case, I use the s:text tag for constants being displayed in the UI like titles or button labels. But indeed, I prefer JSON usually.

Comment: @OFFEN What the json contains isn't relevant.

Comment: @gstackoverflow That seems to be a completely unrelated question; please don't use comments as a way to draw attention to unrelated activity.